# Add user's first and last name to every page in ASP.NET Core 3 Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I've been using ASP.NET WebForms for the past year and would like to move on to ASP.NET Core and Razor Pages. All apps are run on the domain and use Windows Authentication. I'd like to know the best way to put the user's first and last name on every page. I've seen articles about dependency injection, middleware, controllers, `IHttpContextAccessor`, and I'm just lost.

As a test, I set up a new ASP.NET Core 3 Razor Pages project and enabled Windows Authentication, and set up `Index.cshtml.cs` like so:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace RazorTemplate.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        ...

        public void OnGet()
        {
            var username = User.Identity.Name;
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain"))
            {
                var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, username);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    ViewData["FirstName"] = user.GivenName;
                    ViewData["LastName"] = user.Surname;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `Index.cshtml`:

```
Hello, @ViewData["FirstName"] @ViewData["LastName"]!
```

which works, but I want that in the `<header>` of `_Layout.cshtml`. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: you could use a javascript in "_Layout" which gets back the first and last name from a controller and then populate the header that way.  Placeholder could just be <div id = 'username'>@User.Identity.Name</div>, and on success you replace that with first and last.  Though it would have to call FindByIdentity for every page.  Might want to use a cookie or storage.